Excluding certain Vue routes and components with Laravel + Vite based on authentication
I have an extensive SPA using Vue3, served by Laravel 10. I am using Vite for all of my JS source-code management. I.e., npm run dev in local environment and npm run build in production.
At the moment, everything is included in the javascript in one way or another, this is exposing certain system architecture and back-end routes only meant for internal use. I need to exclude these files based on the user's authentication status and permissions.
Obviously, the exclusion of these files needs to be done within the PHP, in previous projects, this has been achieved in the blade root blade template and only including different JS files. I am enjoying using Vite and the way it bundles everything together and certain plugins such as uploading assets to S3.
Is there perhaps a way I can define two separate asset builds? One that does not exclude anything, to be included in the blade template for users with the utmost permissions, and one that excludes sensitive files and business logic, to be included for unauthenticated/low-permission users?
I can't find an easy answer to this online, so any help would be much appreciated.
I have tried to use Vite rollup options without any joy.
